# Speed of memcpy() greatly influenced by different ways of malloc()

Tags: performance, gcc, malloc, memcpy, cpu-cache

I wrote a program to test the speed of `memcpy()`. However, how memory are allocated greatly influences the speed.

## CODE

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/time.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned char * pbuff_1;
    unsigned char * pbuff_2;
    unsigned long iters = 1000*1000;

    int type = atoi(argv[1]);
    int buff_size = atoi(argv[2])*1024;

    if(type == 1){ 
        pbuff_1 = (void *)malloc(2*buff_size);
        pbuff_2 = pbuff_1+buff_size;
    }else{
        pbuff_1 = (void *)malloc(buff_size);
        pbuff_2 = (void *)malloc(buff_size);
    }   

    for(int i = 0; i < iters; ++i){
        memcpy(pbuff_2, pbuff_1, buff_size);
    }   

    if(type == 1){ 
        free(pbuff_1);
    }else{
        free(pbuff_1);
        free(pbuff_2);
    }   
}
```

The OS is linux-2.6.35 and the compiler is GCC-4.4.5 with options "-std=c99 -O3".

Results on my computer(`memcpy` 4KB, iterate 1 million times):

time ./test.test 1 4

```
real    0m0.128s
user    0m0.120s
sys 0m0.000s
```

time ./test.test 0 4

```
real    0m0.422s
user    0m0.420s
sys 0m0.000s
```

This question is related with a previous question:

[Why does the speed of memcpy() drop dramatically every 4KB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038965/why-speed-of-memcpy-drops-dramatically-every-4kb)

## UPDATE

The reason is related with GCC compiler, and I compiled and run this program with different versions of GCC:

GCC version--------`4.1.3`--------`4.4.5`--------`4.6.3`

Time Used(1)-----`0m0.183s`----`0m0.128s`----`0m0.110s`

Time Used(0)-----`0m1.788s`----`0m0.422s`----`0m0.108s`

It seems GCC is getting smarter.

Comment: Strange, I couldn't reproduce this result on gcc 4.6.3 (i'm getting ~0.400 on both cases). Are you sure you didn't switch the args and run over 1k?

Comment: @Leeor I am sure it run over 4KB, and the same result only recurs over 4*i KB in my laptop as well as a server. Both two CPUs have a 32KB L1d 8-way associative cache.

Comment: @Leeor I guess it's relevant with `GCC` compiler. when I update GCC version to 4.6.3, time of two cases are the same.

Comment: very difficult to believe that "time ./test 0 4" is taking less time than "time ./test.test 1 4". My test shows otherwise with gcc 4.6.3

Comment: @VikramSingh Can you give exact time of these two cases?

Answer (score 3):

The specific addresses returned by malloc are selected by the implementation and not always optimal for the using code. You already know that the speed of moving memory around depends greatly on cache and page effects.

Here, the specific pointers malloced are not known. You could print them out using `printf("%p", ptr)`. What is known however, is that using just one malloc for two blocks surely avoids page and cache waste between the two blocks. That may already be the reason for the speed difference.

Comment: When `type==1`, two buffers was allocated contiguously, `type==0`, there is a gap of 16 Bytes between two buffers.