# Debugging the CPU Caches

Tags: c++, c, performance, caching, cpu-cache

I'm currently trying to optimize my software for better CPU cache usage. There are some posts on SO which suggest that it's sometimes **hard to guess** what the CPU cache is doing and why there are some performance drops in certain cases. For example:

- [Why does the speed of memcpy() drop dramatically every 4KB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21038965/773690)
- [Why is my program slow when looping over exactly 8192 elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264970/why-is-my-program-slow-when-looping-over-exactly-8192-elements)
- [Why is transposing a matrix of 512x512 much slower than transposing a matrix of 513x513?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413855/why-is-transposing-a-matrix-of-512x512-much-slower-than-transposing-a-matrix-of)

So in order to get a clue where the cache misses happen, I can run `perf` to get a count of cache misses and where they occur as well as `valgrind --tool=cachegrind` to simulate the caches (at least an L1 and a last-level cache).

It's really nice to know **where** cache misses happen, but I'd like to know **why** they happen (for example cache trashing etc.). Is there a way to explicitly pause the program and see whats inside the caches (maybe with the program running in `valgrind` and `vgdb` attached)?

Comment: There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.

Comment: @themagicalyang: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation, naming things and off-by-one errors". Please don't mutilate well known proverbs.

Comment: You don't want to see 'why' they happen at individual times, but 'why' they happen that often.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you'll need to disassemble your binary and, look to see where the program is using the cache. Look to see where the prefetch or cache instructions are called. That will give you the where and whys of it. It's an unfortunately painful process.