# Getting cache details in ARM processors - Linux

Tags: linux, arm, cpu-cache

On Intel processors

```
Linux linux-epq2.site 3.7.10-1.11-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 16 20:27:27 UTC 2013 (adf31bb) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

to fetch the cache details:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cache/index*/
```

Where * is the respective cpu and cache index numbers

However, on ARM processors, this file/folder is not available. Is there a way to fetch these details?

```
Linux arndale 3.9.0-rc5+ #8 SMP Tue Apr 9 12:40:32 CEST 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Any ideas? I didn't find any solution so far.

Comment: No.  In the [ARM kernel directory](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel), there is no *arm_cacheinfo.c*, like in the [intel_cacheinfo.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/intel_cacheinfo.c) file.  There are some `MRC p15...` that can retrieve this information, but it is not in Linux currently.

Comment: Thanks! Hope they implement it soon

Answer (score 0):

From ARMv8A (64bit), it is possible to get cache info from CLIDR register. So cache info can be populated to /sys file system in Linux. Check detail from kernel/arch/arm64/kernel/cacheinfo.c.

Comment: BTW, the simulator by qemu-system-aarch64 doesn't show cache info from /cache. It doesn't mean ARM64 doesn't support cache info in Linux. That is a "bug" of default device tree created by Qemu. It should add next-level-cache in CPU node.